# Database Query for join the table

Tags: sql

I have two tables. If the first table (friend email) matches the second table (user id), 
then I insert this record into a third table. In 3rd table

```
u1-->useremail  
u2-->Friendemail
```

then it also contains

```
u2-->useremail  
u1-->Friendemail
```

Is it possible using query???

**table 1**

```
Useremail        Friendemail

 1. u1             u2
 2. u1             u3
 3. u1             u4
 4. u2             u3
```

**table 2**

```
 id
 u1
 u2
 u3
```

**table 3**

```
Useremail   Friendemail
1. u1             u2
2. u1             u3
3. u2             u3
4. u2             u1
5. u3             u1
6. u3             u2
```

Answer (score 1):

First select the data using select query and apply joins then insert into table

```
 insert into table3(usermail,friendmail) (select table1.usermail,table1.friendmail from table1 inner join table2 on table1.usermail=table2.userid and table1.friendmail in (select userid from table2) union select table1.friendmail,table1.usermail from table1 inner join table2 on table1.friendmail=table2.userid and table1.usermail in (select userid from table2) );
```

May be it will help you.....

Comment: @user1241838 now try this       insert into table3(usermail,friendmail) (select table1.usermail,table1.friendmail from table1 inner join table2 on table1.usermail=table2.userid and table1.friendmail in (select userid from table2) union select table1.friendmail,table1.usermail from table1 inner join table2 on table1.friendmail=table2.userid and table1.usermail in (select userid from table2) );

Comment: @user1241838 previously i forgot to change the order of select statements that's why its giving only 3 result now its giving 6 result according to your requirement